# How do I force child controls or layouts to be the same width as the parent in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NGIC_XAML.Views.Payments.Payments">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <FlexLayout Direction="Column" AlignItems="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="108" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Payments" TextColor="#F9F8FA" FontSize="20" Margin="40"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I want the outer layout, the FlexLayout, to automatically size the width to the device's maximum. I want the Layout (the StackLayout) and child Control (the Label), to also automatically resize their widths to the FlexLayout. I am stumped as to how to do this. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [FlexLayout docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout), they mention "The HorizontalOptions property doesn't work for children of a FlexLayout".

If you take a look at the [Page layout with FlexLayout section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout#page-layout-with-flexlayout) (Holy Grail Layout) you can see an example somewhat similar to what you are trying to accomplish, basically use a nested FlexLayout instead of a StackLayout.

The code would look like:

```
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <FlexLayout 
                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                Direction="Column">
                <FlexLayout
                    HeightRequest="108"
                    AlignItems="Center"
                    Direction="Column"
                    BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Label 
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
                        Text="Payments" 
                        TextColor="#F9F8FA" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        Margin="40"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Label>                    
                </FlexLayout>
            </FlexLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image: sample screenshot]

Notice that the label will grow as needed to use the full width of the row.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, please assign `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to StackLayout and Label and other child controls if any.
This will tell the controls to fill all the space available horizontally.

Thanks!

Comment: I modified the XAML to use the FillAndExpand and that did not work. See the image of the rendered page above. I also tried using just Fill on the FlexLayout and that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to remove the Margin="40" assigned to the Label and FlexLayout AlignItems="Stretch". This will make it work. Thanks!